# Existing data in Peers is not getting synced

Tags: gun

I tried setting up the gun.js server code in two machines and set up up 2 browser clients in each machine which contains code for registering both the machines as peers.The server code for both machines has put statements for 2 different nodes

Scneario 1
Started both servers:Existing Data not syncing

Scenario 2
Statred both Servers and both Clients:Existing Data not syncing

Scenario 3
Put a new data item(distinct) from each browser console.The newly put data gets synced in both machines.

Please guide in resolving this issue.

Thanks
FirstTry

Comment: or is it possibly related to this issue? https://github.com/amark/gun/issues/408

Answer (score 0):

@FirstTrial I did not downvote the question (I am not sure why or who did).

I'm not able to replicate the issue from your explanation, here is a way that can test what is going on:

https://github.com/gundb/panic-server

We created a distributed testing tool to simulate failures and stress test the system.

Here is an extremely well documented example in less than 300 lines: https://github.com/amark/gun/blob/master/test/panic/load.js

There is a very similar PANIC test to what you describe, and it passes OK without any errors, you can check it out here: https://github.com/amark/gun/blob/master/test/panic/b2s2s2b.js

Let me know!